# Send key for message when using Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am using iOS 8 and a Apple Bluetooth Keyboard. I cannot find the key combination to send a message in Messages. For example, Mail has Command + Shift + D, Facebook has Command + Return. Anyone know the shortcut for messages?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. In previous versions of iOS you could change a setting in Keyboards, however it doesn't seem to work in iOS 8. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Try **CONTROL** + **Return** keys. 
Works for me.

[image: macbluetoothkeyboard]

Answer (score -1):

Try it now. I have iOS9.3.3 in use on my iPad and <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> sent my email in the Mail app with no problem.